# How to retain Fragments from backstack on orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes

How can I retain fragments from backstack on orientation changes?

I'm using this code to add fragments to backstack:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But they disappear when I change device orientation.

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of fragments in Google Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I retain fragments from backstack on orientation changes?

AFAIK, you don't. Instead, you have other fragment(s), such as a model fragment, that you retain.

Bear in mind that Google's official recommendation is for fragments with UI to *never* be retained, due to the risk of developers screwing up and holding onto things related to the old activity that they shouldn't. Personally, I think that recommendation is overkill.

> I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of fragments in Google Play.

I am not quite certain what you are referring to here. There's no way from outside an app to determine if that app is retaining fragments or not.